# How to setAlarmManager at Dialog fragment in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcast, dialogfragment

I am creating a alerm type notification for my application.But facing a null pointer error.From a dialogfragment, AlarmManager indicating the null. Here is my code.

```
if(alermId>=0){
         Log.e("Alerm Id: ",""+alermId);
            Intent alermReceiver = new Intent(getActivity(), AlermReceiver.class);
            alermReceiver.setAction(DietInformation.ACTION_DIET);
            alermReceiver.putExtra("title",titleView.getText());
            alermReceiver.putExtra("day",repeatView.getText());
            alermReceiver.putExtra("menu",menuView.getText());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),alermId,alermReceiver,0);
            //ApplicationData.getAlarmManager().setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,reminderTimeInMills,24*60*60*1000*7,pendingIntent);
            //ApplicationMain.getAlarmManager().setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,reminderTimeInMills,24*60*60*1000*7,pendingIntent);
             //alarmManager =
           AlarmClass.getAlarmManager().setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,reminderTimeInMills,24*60*60*1000*7,pendingIntent);
        }
```

And for instantiating the Alarmanager I created a inner class like as follows

```
   static class AlarmClass extends Application{
           public static AlarmManager alarmManager;
           AlarmClass(){
               alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
           }
           public static AlarmManager getAlarmManager() {
               return alarmManager;
           }
       }
```

But application shows up an null pointer error. like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AlarmManager.setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)' on a null object reference
            at com.softmaker.gazi_opu.personalhealthcare.fragment.CreateDietFragment.setReminder(CreateDietFragment.java:406)
```

Can anyone suggest me. How to instantiate the alarmMenager for setRepeating(....);

Answer (score 2):

try changing the code in your application class

```
static class AlarmClass extends Application{
       public static AlarmManager alarmManager;
       Context mContext;
       AlarmClass(){
           mContext = this;
           alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       }
       public static AlarmManager getAlarmManager() {

           if(alarmManager==null){

             alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

           }
           return alarmManager;
       }
   }
```

Comment: I tried in this way ... but it didn't work... Another thing, As I extends Application, Should I add onCreate() method ???